# confusion about the equality of codebase when using loadfrom?

Tags: c#, .net

```
// path1 and path2 point to different copies of the same assembly on disk:

    Assembly assembly1 = Assembly.LoadFrom(path1);
    Assembly assembly2 = Assembly.LoadFrom(path2);

// These both point to the assembly from path1, so this is true

Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(assembly1.CodeBase, assembly2.CodeBase) == 0);
```

Why assembly.Code is the same as assembly2.CodeBase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly it's due to this (from the docs for [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx)):

> If an assembly with the same identity is already loaded, LoadFrom returns the loaded assembly even if a different path was specified.

Have you checked whether `assembly1` and `assembly2` are actually identical references?

Comment: @AdamLee: Well there we go then - you're trying to load the same assembly *identity* twice. As the docs mention, you could try using `Load` instead of `LoadFrom`. Or you may need to use multiple app domains.